# Creating a mysqldump file

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Goal: migrate google-cloud-sql First Generation to second generation

Exporting Data from Cloud SQL is working fine.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/backup-recovery/backing-up
But:
Note: If you are exporting your data for use in a Cloud SQL instance, you must use the instructions provided in Exporting data for Import into Cloud SQL. You cannot use these instructions.

So i get to this page:
Exporting Data for Import into Cloud SQL
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export/creating-mysqldump-csv#mysqldump

This pages describes how to create a mysqldump or CSV file from a MySQL database that does not reside in Cloud SQL.

Instructions are not working:
mysqldump --databases [DATABASE_NAME] -h [INSTANCE_IP] -u [USERNAME] -p \
--hex-blob --skip-triggers --set-gtid-purged=OFF --default-character-set=utf8 > [DATABASE_FILE].sql

mysqldump: unknown variable 'set-gtid-purged=OFF

How do I create mysqldump for import in cloud sql second generation?

thanks in advance,
Sander

edit:
Using google cloud sql first generation via google cloud console

removed set-gtid-purged=OFF
result:
Enter password: 
mysqldump: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 when trying to connect
s@folkloric-alpha-618:~$

Comment: What version of mysqldump are you trying this with? This probably means that your version of mysqldump doesn't support set-gtid-purge yet. On ubuntu 14.04 that's the case. Try to remove it from the command line and run it again.

Comment: Done:, Enter password: 
mysqldump: Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0 when trying to connect
s@folkloric-alpha-618:~$

Comment: It sounds like you have not authorized your IP address to connect to the instance you are trying to export from. You can confirm by running `mysql -h <IP> -u <USER> -p` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: You need to authorize the IP you are connecting from: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external#appaccessIP

Comment: How and why? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/import-export/exporting<br> Export via gcloud sql instances export [INSTANCE_NAME] gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/sqldumpfile.gz --database [DATABASE_NAMES   is woking fine. Only via mysqldumop it is not working.

Comment: I will try to find the google console ip and grant acces.

Comment: Removing it from the command line is not advisable. From https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/creating-sqldump-csv#sqldump - "--set-gtid-purged=OFF GTID information must not be included in the SQL dump file"

Answer (score 1):

For `set-gtid-purged`. Please verify which `mysql-client` version you have installed. Many OS come with the MariaDB version which does not support this flag (since their implementation of GTID is different).

I know the Oracle official `mysql-client` supports this flag [since 5.6.9](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-gtids-failover.html).

To verify your package run:

```
mysqldump --version
```

If you get this, **you don't have** the official client:

```
mysqldump  Ver 10.16 Distrib 10.1.41-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64)
```

The official client would be something like this:

```
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64)
```

---

If you want to change the version, you can use [their official repository](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/).